# MySQL UPDATE with CAST/CONVERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel like this should be very simple but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong;

My query looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET varchar_column = CAST(int_column AS VARCHAR(255)) WHERE ...
```

But I keep getting an error saying there is a syntax error; I also tried using `CONVERT(int_column,VARCHAR(255))` but the same thing is happening?

Does anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually tring to do?

Answer (score 1):

`CAST()` does not accept `VARCHAR(n)` as a target type, as explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html). You can use `CHAR(n)` instead (or `NCHAR(n)` for national character set):

```
UPDATE table_name SET varchar_column = CAST(int_column AS CHAR(255)) WHERE ...
```

Note: the length of the string is optional (it is actually there only to define a maximum length for the target string).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will do implicit conversion, so you don't need to be explicit:

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET varchar_column = int_column ;
```

That said, explicit conversion is usually a good idea.  MySQL does not take a length argument for strings.

Answer (score 0):

It should be cast(int_column as CHAR)

See an example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ebdc64f999c507e4fc1d4d1b892a1dce

Answer (score 0):

Casting to VARCHAR is not supported. You'll need to cast to CHAR:

```
UPDATE table_name SET varchar_column = CAST(int_column AS CHAR) WHERE ...
```

See [CONVERT/CAST documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/convert/)