# Is there a way to update ONLY field.type data onto SQL using dbWriteTable? Without having to pass the whole table's value

Tags: sql, r, database, dbi

So pretty much I am pulling a whole table from my database using:

```
ss_data<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = ,password=, host= ,dbname= )
Combined_Query<-gsub("[\r\n]"," ",paste0("select * FROM ",table_name))
Q_temp<-dbSendQuery(ss_data,Combined_Query)
temp<-fetch(Q_temp, n=-1)
report_pull<-rbind(report_pull,temp) 
dbDisconnect(ss_data)
```

So this pulls my data as I need. After that perform some tests and to check the size of each column. I reassign field types based on my test. After that I would send the data back to the database using:

```
fieldtype<- setNames(newcoltypes, colnames(report_pull))
ss_data<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user =  ,password= , host= ,dbname= )
dbWriteTable(ss_data, value= report_pull, name="datatest1" ,overwrite=TRUE,row.names=FALSE, field.types = fieldtype)
dbDisconnect(ss_data)
```

Because I am not manipulating any of the data and I'm sending it back, I was wondering if there was a way to only send field.type data.

I am going to be doing this for ~500GB worth of tables, it would greatly reduce time spent if I didn't have to keep pushing back the row values every time.

EDIT:
After reading the comments I started updating in my loop.

```
for (x in 1:ncol(report_pull)){
  ss_data<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = ,password=, host=,dbname=)
  a <- unique(report_pull[x])
  a[a==""] <- NA
  a <- na.omit(a)
  if (length(a[,]) != 0){
    if ((grepl("^[0-9.]+$", a[,] )) == TRUE){
      if ((grepl("^[0-9]+$", a[,] )) == TRUE){
        if (typeof(report_pull[,x]) == "double"){
          dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` double;"))
          listofcol[x] <- "double"}
        else { # For int, we need to make it tiny text, int isnt working on our DB
          dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` tinytext;"))
          listofcol[x] <- "int - tinytext"}
      }
      else {
        dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` double;"))
        listofcol[x] <- "double"
      }
    }
    else {
      if (between(max(nchar(a[,])), 50, 255)) {
        dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` varchar(255);"))
        listofcol[x] <- paste0("varchar(255)")}
      else if (max(nchar(a[,])) > 255) { 
        dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` tinytext;"))
        listofcol[x] <- paste0("tinytext") }
      else {
        dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` varchar(", max(nchar(a[,])),");"))
        listofcol[x] <- paste0("varchar(", max(nchar(a[,])),")")}
    }
    
    if (grepl("url|URL", (colnames(report_pull[x] ))) == TRUE){
      dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` tinytext;"))
      listofcol[x] <- "tinytext"
    }
  }
  else { 
    print(paste0("Element ",x[1], " has 0 entries."))
    dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` varchar(255);"))
    listofcol[x] <- "varchar(255)"
  }
  dbDisconnect(ss_data)
}
```

the issue I am facing is in this line of code:

```
dbExecute(ss_data,paste0("ALTER TABLE ",table," MODIFY COLUMN `", colnames(report_pull[x]) ,"` tinytext;"))
```

The error I get on both DB and on R saying Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

I think the issue is that when this table was made, all the field types were set as TEXT. Im just having a hard to setting it to int.

Comment: By *"only send field.type"*, does that mean you want to change the type of the data columns in the database? That is a SQL-only operation, you can't change that from R. (You may not be able to change it in SQL without additional permissions.)

Comment: If you're going to use `dbSendQuery` and `fetch`, you need to `dbClearResult(Q_temp)`; but better yet just do `temp <- dbGetQuery(ss_data, Combined_query)` *once*, it handles clearing the resultset (but you still need to `dbDisconnect`, of course). Or you can use ``DBI::dbReadTable(table_name)` without needing to prepend `select * from`.

Comment: Instead of sending the ***data*** back, iterate over your columns and where the datatype is to be changed, run a statement such as `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar VARCHAR(6);` using `dbExecute`.  *(Note, that's a SQL Server example, the actual syntax will vary from database to database.  These types of DML / Data Modelling Language statements aren't abstracted, you need to code the SQL yourself.  That you want/need to do this regularly is a worrying code-smell.)*

Comment: @r2evans 
Thanks for commenting. I used the code I mentioned and it works fine in sending the data col types. I checked on my DB tool and all the field types have been changed from text to w.e I set them as. I just am hoping there is a way to send only field type info.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I do not use your method of `overwrite=TRUE`, since when dealing with large amounts of data, it seems rather inefficient to be doing that. No, in R there is no way to *just* upload field types. As @MatBailie suggested, you need to `ALTER TABLE` the existing table data (no overwrite). Do you really need to download all 500GB of data to be able to deduce what the new field types should be? I wonder if you can do it with a few hundred (or fewer) rows.

Comment: @r2evans I do need to download it. Check the size of the unique rows. Reassigning based on some rules. I've tried MatBailie's method but I'm running into an issue with modifying a col to int type. ERROR: Incorrect integer value for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: *"size of unique rows"* can be done (perhaps more efficiently) in SQL; if your heuristics are simple enough, perhaps it can be done without downloading all 500GB of data. Regardless (you know better, of course), you'll need to [edit] your question and add the `ALTER TABLE` code and the error for us to be able to help. I'm not a MySQL expert, perhaps it's general enough I can help (or somebody else with more experience will be able to chime in).

Comment: Reading https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/198627/156305, it seems a plausible way-forward would be to create a new `INT` column, then query/coerce the data from `TEXT` to `INT` (via "cast" or such) into this new column, then when you're comfortable, drop the original text column and rename the new one to the original name.

Comment: There is at least one more problem with your script: `if ((grepl("^[0-9.]+$", a[,] )) == TRUE)` is almost guaranteed to be emitted *warnings* to you along the lines of `the condition has length > 1`, suggesting that you are using `if` or `grepl` incorrectly, perhaps you mean to use `all(grepl(...))`? (Nit: the `== TRUE` is redundant/unnecessary.)

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that all columns begin as `TEXT` or `varchar(max)` or similar?

Comment: Yes, all of them begin as TEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain that this will fix all of your woes, but it's an in-database method (with *some* help from R) for redefining column types. I'm assuming the data is uploaded always as `TEXT` regardless of the actual data, so this process will attempt to fix this.

### Docker setup

Not required for your setup, but useful if anybody else needs to test this.

```sh
$ docker pull mysql:8.0.26
$ docker run -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:8.0.26
```

Confirm connection in R:

```r
my <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver", pwd="my-secret-pw", uid="root")
DBI::dbGetQuery(my, "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';")
#   Variable_name  Value
# 1       version 8.0.26
DBI::dbExecute(my, "create schema stackoverflow")
DBI::dbExecute(my, "use stackoverflow")
```

And when demos/tests are complete (after running the rest of this answer's code),

```r
DBI::dbExecute(my, "drop table sometable")
DBI::dbExecute(my, "drop schema stackoverflow")
```

### Fake data

```r
DBI::dbWriteTable(my, "sometable", data.frame(
  longstring = c("a very long string here that is going to trigger perhaps a varchar(255)",
                 "234", "3.1415"),
  somefloat = c("234", "3.1415", "2.718271828"),
  someint = c("234", "3", "2"),
  longerstring = c(strrep("A", 260), "A", "A")
))
```

### Retrieve table stats

This is where most of the 'pain' will be felt: I have not tested this on gargantuan tables, so please provide some feedback. Since it uses a lot of `REGEXP`, I don't assume that it will return in milliseconds, but perhaps it's faster than downloading and loading into R.

```r
tests <- do.call(rbind, lapply(DBI::dbListFields(my, "sometable"), function(nm) {
  DBI::dbGetQuery(my, sprintf("
    select 
      %s as column_name,
      count(*) as n,
      sum(%s regexp '^[-+]?.*[^0-9.].*$') as nonnumber,
      sum(%s regexp '^[-+]?.*[^0-9].*$') as nonint,
      max(length(%s)) as maxlen
    from sometable where %s is not null and %s <> ''", sQuote(nm), nm, nm, nm, nm, nm))
}))
tests
#    column_name n nonnumber nonint maxlen
# 1   longstring 3         1      2     71
# 2    somefloat 3         0      2     11
# 3      someint 3         0      0      3
# 4 longerstring 3         3      3    260
```

From here, we need to use these "rules" to determine what the new column type should be. I'm using `dplyr::case_when` because I find it much better than nested `ifelse` or the like. If you're using `dplyr` in general, then this will fit right in to your current dialect and toolset; if you're using `data.table`, then it should be rather straight-forward to translate this to `data.table::fcase`.

```r
tests$new_type <- with(tests, dplyr::case_when(
  n == 0                   ~ "varchar(255)",
  grepl("url", column_name, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "tinytext",
  nonint == 0              ~ "tinytext", # For int, we need to make it tiny text, int isnt working on our DB
  nonnumber == 0           ~ "double",
  maxlen < 50              ~ "tinytext",
  between(maxlen, 50, 255) ~ "varchar(255)",
  TRUE                     ~ sprintf("varchar(%s)", maxlen)))
tests
#    column_name n nonnumber nonint maxlen     new_type
# 1   longstring 3         1      2     71 varchar(255)
# 2    somefloat 3         0      2     11       double
# 3      someint 3         0      0      3     tinytext
# 4 longerstring 3         3      3    260 varchar(260)
```

You will need to review these rules carefully to make sure they capture all of your intent. However, I think the *premise* of simple rules like this (and the four "meta" columns I stored into `tests`) is a good start.

### Update the columns

Copying the method from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198635/156305, I'll loop over the rows, create a new column as the new type, copy/`CAST` from the old column, remove the old column, then rename the new to the original name.

I'll show the column data types before and after the conversion.

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(my, "select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name='sometable'")
#    COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
# 1 longerstring      text                    65535
# 2   longstring      text                    65535
# 3    somefloat      text                    65535
# 4      someint      text                    65535

for (rownum in seq_len(nrow(tests))) {
  nm <- tests$column_name[rownum]
  typ <- tests$new_type[rownum]
  typ2 <- 
    if (grepl("varchar", typ)) {
      gsub("var", "", typ)
    } else if (typ == "tinytext") {
      "char(50)"
    } else typ
  message(sprintf("Converting column '%s' to '%s' ('%s')", nm, typ, typ2))
  DBI::dbExecute(my, sprintf("ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN newcolumn %s", typ))
  DBI::dbExecute(my, sprintf("UPDATE sometable SET newcolumn = cast(%s as %s)", nm, typ2))
  DBI::dbExecute(my, sprintf("ALTER TABLE sometable DROP COLUMN %s", nm))
  DBI::dbExecute(my, sprintf("ALTER TABLE sometable RENAME COLUMN newcolumn to %s", nm))
}
# Converting column 'longstring' to 'varchar(255)' ('char(255)')
# Converting column 'somefloat' to 'double' ('double')
# Converting column 'someint' to 'tinytext' ('char(50)')
# Converting column 'longerstring' to 'varchar(260)' ('char(260)')

DBI::dbGetQuery(my, "select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name='sometable'")
#    COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
# 1 longerstring   varchar                      260
# 2   longstring   varchar                      255
# 3    somefloat    double                     <NA>
# 4      someint  tinytext                      255
```

And to prove that the data is still present and correct,

```r
str(DBI::dbGetQuery(my, "select * from sometable"))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ longstring  : chr  "a very long string here that is going to trigger perhaps a varchar(255)" "234" "3.1415"
#  $ somefloat   : num  234 3.14 2.72
#  $ someint     : chr  "234" "3" "2"
#  $ longerstring: chr  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"| __truncated__ "A" "A"
```

### Caveats

- I do not have much experience with the performance of `REGEXP`, I might be abusing a "heavy tool" here.
- Copying data from one column to the other may not be cheap, I have not tested with "large-ish data".
- I use `char(.)` and `varchar(.)`, you may prefer to use `nchar(.)` and `nvarchar(.)`, depending on your data.
- The reason I create `typ2` is because MySQL does not accept `cast(.. as varchar(n))` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59179977/3358272); it also appears to not like `cast(.. as tinytext)`. Ergo the temporary translation during `cast`ing.
- There may be much more MySQL-canonical ways to do many of these steps. I do not profess MySQL guru-status by any stretch.

Comment: What do you think, @abdullaharshad18? Am I close?

Comment: I apologize. This answer did work for me. I do appreciate the effort you put into it. I am still a bit new to hosting a question on StackOverflow. You did do a lot and hit the nail on the head. It's weird that I don't get email notifications for comments/answers. I apologize for responding so late. This saved me a lot of time on my scripts and a lot more space on my server. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I really wanted email notifications as well, and I found it (some time ago): click on your username, then click the `Edit profile` button (top right), then on the left under "Email Settings", click `Edit email settings`. You should see the ability to change your **Inbox** setting from "off" to 3 hours, daily, or weekly. At least, that's what I see on mine. I'm really glad this answer worked for you!